# My TDS does not earn any credits while I'm not playing

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

My TDS does not earn any credits while I am not playing.  It worked for the first day (got $9000 the first night), but since then it doesn't change no matter how long I wait.

Also, I can't access various tabs in the options screen (e.g. can't access levels or scenes tabs in album and can't order bitizens by skill tabs).

Anyone know how to fix these issues?  I think it will require an update.

Comment: can you reinstall the game?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Sales When I'm away from game](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143285/no-sales-when-im-away-from-game)

Comment: @Ullallulloo It probably should be the other way around. This is the older question. [No Sales When I'm away from game](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/143285/4797) *is* a possible duplicate of *this* question.

Answer (score 2):

Okey, I think I have the solution - for Windows Phone at least, but it might apply to Android and IOS also.

When they updated the game with the holyday stuff I noticed that I was not earning when I close the application.

But then I tombstoned the application, on Windows Phone you can "sleep" the application - it does not close, you just put it in the background. 
When I then pulled the application to the screen again I got the scene where you were told how much you have earned while away.

So my conclusion is that if the application is stopped/killed it will not calculate your earnings while you are not running the application. 
I have not tested it for Android, but if it works as with Windows Phone I guess you could tap the "home" button (hardware button) while in the application to put it to sleep. And then longpress your "home" button again to see the list of running applications and select the game.

Tested and worked on Windows Phone

Answer (score 1):

From Tiny tower's [wiki](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Currency), there are four ways to gain currency :

> 1. The sale of products at a commercial floor.
> 2. The stocking of the last item in a commercial floor, as a bonus. (Total # Items / 20 Coins)
> 3. The delivery of a Bitizens to their desired floor, by way of the elevator. (Floor # × 2 Coins)
> 4. The collection of rent from Bitizens. (100 Coins / Bitizen / day)

No. 1 and 4 are passive and you get credits as time pass. If you have no Residential floors or if your Commercial floors don't have any stock, you won't get any passive credits.

Comment: Thanks, but i think it is a glitch (apparently one of many with this game at the moment).  I also don't get the emperor intro screen ("you have earned X credits") and with every new level I build it tells me I have earned the build 10 levels/build one of each level achievement...I have about 20 levels :/