# No Sales When I'm away from game

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've been playing the game for about a week without issue, but all of a sudden today it stopped earning credits while I am away from the game. My stores are stocked, the game is properly counting down time (projects are getting completed), but the only time the game earns credits/has sales is while I'm actively playing it.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Note: I have the game for Android, and there might have been an update today

Comment: Have never encountered this problem. Your problem sounds like the clock is somehow not ticking when you're "away". Playing on an iPhone here.

Comment: Mine appears to be working fine on Android, one thing I have noticed is that it doesn't always give you the screen saying how much you've earned but your credits still appear to increase and time to purchase still seems to reduce

Comment: Have you tried speaking to Disney customer support? NimbleBit does not directly support the game, rather they have asked all customer support issues to be directed to Disney with whom they have partnered. The website and email address can be found by clicking on the wrench on the menu page. http://disneyinteractivestudios.custhelp.com support@disneymobile.com Perhaps they can give you information on how to fix this bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evidently, [other people](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143795) have [this issue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144068), [or similar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141709) as well.

Sadly — because of the [arrangements with Disney](http://support.nimblebit.com/customer/portal/articles/1341962-tiny-death-star-support) — support for *Tiny Death Star* is scarce. The [knowledge base for *Tiny Death Star*](http://disneyinteractivestudios.custhelp.com/app/answers/list/kw/tiny%20death%20star/) reveals only [two](http://disneyinteractivestudios.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4191) separate [bugs](http://disneyinteractivestudios.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4179) related to game progress, neither of which seems to match the described issue.

There is [this discussion about it on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/tinydeathstar/comments/1rc4m0/anyone_else_having_this_problem/); this bug appears to be present on *both* iOS and Android in one way or another.

As a conclusion, contacting [Disney support](http://disneyinteractivestudios.custhelp.com) seems to be your best bet right now.

Comment: Oh sure!!!  I make this same post as an answer and I get told it has to be a comment!  And, you come along and get to post it and get the rep for the answer!!!!!!!  LMAO!!!!

Comment: @DavidM Notice how it's a **comunity wiki**? Nobody's getting any rep for it. The answer was made so we can *close duplicates of this*.

Comment: Oh, OK . . . LOL.  I meant it in a light-hearted way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on an actual Android device and not the emulator or one of the stacks that let you run on a PC?  Emulator and PC would suffer from same problem of not incrementing your clock elapsed time correctly.

Otherwise the only thing I can think of is that your Android device didn't implement the timer correctly (would be REALLY hard to do that though).  What device is it?

Comment: Ruining on my Android based Samsung phone. As I've said above, it is NOT a problem with the clock. The clock is still counting when I'm away from the game. I just get no sales at all - there is no traffic to the floors when I am not actively playing. I have 28 floors and 50 bitizens - I don't want to delete/reinstall it, but I'm thinking that's my only choice...